# $_GET and $_POST without form action

Tags: php

In a form, I am trying to get the value of POST data.

The code is like this:

```
$output .="<div class='name'>Post Name</div>";
$output .="<div class='edit'><a href="someline?postid">Edit</a></div>";
$output .="<div class='delete'><input type='buttom' name='delete'value='Delete'/> </div>"

ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    echo "it works";
};
$output .=ob_get_clean();
return $output;
```

But nothing happened. Any help and idea is helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: do a `print_r($_POST)` to see what variables are being transmitted

Comment: How did you submit your form?

Comment: Did you submit the form? Is both pieces of code in the same file?

Comment: You have no `action="?"` set yet. As in => `<form...` ;-)

Comment: @Fred — Given the subject of the question, that isn't much of a surprise.

Comment: Actually it even doesn't form before, original is like this:   <input type="button" value="testing" name="test"/>

Comment: @Quentin True. But don't you just LOVE SURPRISES?! And it's not even my birthday yet!

Comment: I guess I fell into THAT trap.

Comment: I'm wondering who upvoted the question. Wasn't "moi", that's for sure.

Comment: Ouhh... the **plot** thickens. The OP has added something in an edit. Let's see what other **surprises** we're going to get. Did I mention it wasn't my birthday yet? *Lucky me*.

Comment: FYI: Oh, nor did I downvote. **un-biased** at best.

Comment: @Pluto Google "html form submit" to see how it's done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$_POST` will only be populated in response to a POST request, which a browser will make when you *submit* the form. Just having the form in the page won't do anything.

You need to add `<input type="submit">` and click it.

---

A comment on the question says this:

> Actually it even doesn't form before, original is like this: `<input type="button" value="testing" name="test"/>`

I'm not sure what this is attempting to say, but an input of `type="button"` is designed to *do nothing*. It is a control that you can bind JavaScript to. If you want to submit a form you need an `<input>` or `<button>` of `type="submit"`.

Comment: (**+1**) => For a well-formed answer. Cheers

Comment: Well formed indeed, spot on :)

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis Ah yes => **"Spot on"**. Haven't heard that bit of an expression in a while! *Good one*

Comment: "Just having the form in the page won't do anything" - that's right, but I don't see any form there...

Comment: @Pluto **8 upvotes** counted so far for this one. Worthy of an **accepted answer**, *wouldn't you agree?* ;-)

Comment: @alfasin — The question underwent [significant revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17196777/1)

Comment: I stand corrected, **9**.

Answer (score -2):

Just to round-out your options, you can also get the value via jQuery, before you submit (i.e. POST) the form.

Here is an example: ([jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9mMLz/))

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    var t = $('#tst').val();
                    alert("here is the value: " + t);
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <form method='post'>
        <input id="tst" type="text" value="testing" name="test"/>
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click me">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No please leave jquery out of this, the OP is confused enough.